# Websites keep thinking I'm from France

Tags: google-chrome, powershell, web, private-browsing

This happens mainly in Incognito Mode on Chrome and when using Invoke-Webrequest in Powershell. I always get redirected to French branches of the websites. I've looked up my IP and it does trace to my country of origin which is not France. I also do not have French installed as a second language anywhere.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: There has been no response from poster and this post cannot be improved without interaction of person who posted the question.